# Parse configuration file values

Tags: javascript, regex, configuration-files

I have this configuration file following this format:

```
ALPHA=123456789
BETA=12345
GAMMA=123467
```

and i'd like to get the numeric value only of BETA (so 12345) with a regular expression.
I tried

```
BETA=[^a-zA-Z0-9]+([0-9]+)
```

but it doesn't work.
Any suggestions?

EDIT: i'm using it with JavaScript. I'm writing a Cinnamon extension.

Comment: Which language is involved ? Maybe there's some most proper solutions than regexes

Comment: Regular expression syntax can be highly variable (actually extensions) between implementations.  Usually and `\(*regexp*\)` denotes a match.  For instance, J.T. Blum's answer is very close to a `sed` expression that will work.  However, sputnick's request is a good one.  What langauage/program are you doing this with?

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this:

```
BETA=(\d+)
```

(which is the same as `BETA=([0-9]+)`)

In order to get just the numeric portion, use your language's method of getting the first capture group (In Perl, for example, the result would be contained in `$1` after a successful match).

Your regex (`BETA=[^a-zA-Z0-9]+([0-9]+)`) searches for BETA=, then at least one character that is not a letter or digit, then one or more digits.

This fails because you don't have "at least one character that is not a letter or digit" after the equals sign.

Comment: But it finds the entire line! I want to obtain only the numeric value that is in the line that contains BETA

Comment: @pattern23, the parentheses around the `\d+` put only the numeric portion into a capture group.  You need to use the appropriate mechanism to get the first capture group, rather than the entire match (if you need help with this, please update your question to specify what language you are using--the way of doing this is language-dependent).